# Confusion about the geometric interpretation of covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance

I see some inconsistency in the geometric interpretation of `covariance`.

Here [https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma217/covar.pdf](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/ma217/covar.pdf) and in many other places covariance between two vectors is being interpreted as the inner product of these two vectors.

But according to the covariance formula $${\displaystyle \operatorname {cov} (X,Y)=\sum _{i=1}^{n}p_{i}(x_{i}-E(X))(y_{i}-E(Y)).}$$ and this question from gil strang's book:[image: strang's question]

It can be interpreted that the covariance of two vectors is the inner product of the least square $e$ from their projections onto the line `(1, 1, 1, ...)`.

So which is correct? Covariance of two vectors is the inner product of them or the inner product of the $e$ of each?

Comment: You're a bit confused here. The statement you've linked to *defines* the inner product of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ as the covariance of $X$ and $Y$. That makes *no* appeal/reference to the usual notion of the Euclidean inner product. It just so happens that if $X$ and $Y$ take values in some countable space $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is the Euclidean inner product of the vectors $(a\mathbb{P}(X=a))_{a\in A}$ and $(a\mathbb{P}(Y=a))_{a\in A}$.

Comment: As a side-note, the least squares exercise more so teaches you how to *estimate* means, variances and standard deviations in a linear, Gaussian model than it inherently teaches you anything about covariance. The vectors in the exercise are, after all, perfectly deterministic. No randomness there at all.